# Under-hood explanation required for asp.net MVC tutorial

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

refer to asp.net MVC tutorial:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view

regarding the autogenerated Views\Movies\SearchIndex.cshtml

Question 1:

```
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Genre: @Html.DropDownList("movieGenre", "All")
        Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", "Movies", FormMethod.Get)
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
}
</p>
```

how does **movieGenre** refer to **@ViewBag.movieGenre**, which is obviously defined in Controllers/MoviesController.cs

Question 2:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

where is **modelItem** defined? VS2010 shows me modelItem is

```
IEnumerable <MvcMovie.Model.Movie>
```

Thanks.

Comment: for Q2 check [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: Does @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title) mean what ever the input is (modelItem), it returns item.Title for display? Is it then then the same as @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Title)?

Comment: yes modelItem is any variable. You can write anything that what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've already answered your second question, so I'll just answer your first:

The `Html.DropDownList` helper will bind itself to `ViewData` by default if no data is provided to it. `ViewBag` is simply a dynamic wrapper around the `ViewData` dictionary, so when you set `ViewBag.movieGenre = new SelectList()` you are effectively setting `ViewData["movieGenre"] = new SelectList()`.

Now that you have this `SelectList` in your `ViewData`, the following will automatically bind this to the dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownList("movieGenre")
```

This implicit binding isn't very well documented. See here for more information:

http://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/archive/2012/10/26/mvc-s-html-dropdownlist-and-quot-there-is-no-viewdata-item-of-type-ienumerable-lt-selectlistitem-gt-that-has-the-key.aspx

Comment: Thank you. Puzzle solved. Just wondering: are there the other Html Helpers having the similar data binding, i.e., bind to ViewData by default? Can you please name a few?

Comment: I think this is pretty standard across HtmlHelpers; for example I believe that `@Html.TextBox("movieGenre")` will also pre-populate with `ViewData["movieGenre"]` (untested). The distinction is that `@Html.TextBox` *needs* some form of data source for its options.